Help to identify intermediate language
I have scripts written in PineScript, TradingView's proprietary DSL. Ultimately, Pinescript code gets translated to an intermediate language (IL) presentation, below is an example:
PineScript
//@version=5
indicator(title='ScannerData', shorttitle='_SD_')
// Bond Yield to price
var bond_ticker = str.substring(syminfo.ticker, 0, str.length(syminfo.ticker) - 1)
bond_price = request.security(syminfo.prefix + ":" + bond_ticker, timeframe.period, close, ignore_invalid_symbol=true)
plot(bond_price, title="Bond.Price")
change_abs = bond_price - bond_price[1]
plot(change_abs, title="Bond.Change")
float change_percent = na
if not(bond_price[1] < 0) and not(bond_price < 0)
    change_percent := change_abs / bond_price[1] * 100
plot(change_percent, title="Bond.Change.%")

Intermediate Language
close~$0;$0();#0~$0~$1-$1@1~na():f~v:if(!($1@1<0)&&!($1<0)){$3=($2/$1@1)*100~}~$3~$1!$2!$5;t:str.substring(ticker,0,str.length(ticker):i-1):t~t:sc(t:syminfo.prefix,t:':',t:$3):t~i:na():f~sym($4,period,period,0,0,1,'NONE',0,0,$5)|$1()|s3:$2($7):s3~$9!$10!$11

I am puzzled what kind of language it is? I am familiar with other ILs, e.g. Microsoft or Java, however the aforementioned code bears no resemblance to either.
It is relatively straightforward that the statement
if not(bond_price[1] < 0) and not(bond_price < 0)
    change_percent := change_abs / bond_price[1] * 100

is translated to
v:if(!($1@1<0)&&!($1<0)){$3=($2/$1@1)*100~}

I can deduce that bond_price is translated to $1, change_percent to $3, change_abs to $2.  Array index bond_price[1] becomes $1@1. And so for.
But I wonder what engine or technology would consume such a statement?

googling pinescript intermediate language points to pinescript manual section limitations which says it uses tokenized intermediate language probably some kind of natural language processing  like let  token$1 = bond_price  $1@1 = array access

They say the scripts run (only) on their servers. Some proprietary backend, of course. It's somewhat of a 2nd/3rd year in college project to write an interpreter for something as simple as that. Or even a compiler in a compiler class. How optimized it would be is another question. Possibly they translate to Java, LLVM or something else if they care more about performance.
